# having troubles with angularjs ng-repeat / ng-controller

Tags: angularjs

I have been learning angularjs for 2 days and I can't have it working when dealing with `ng-controller` / `ng-repeat`

```
<html lang="fr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Angular test </title>
  </head>
  <body ng-app>
    Angular test 
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function menuCtrl($scope) {
          $scope.menus = [
            {title:"wiki",img:"../images/profil.png"},
            {title:"list",img:"../images/profil.png"},
            {title:"find",img:"../images/profil.png"},
            {title:"exp",img:"../images/profil.png"},
            {title:"stat",img:"../images/profil.png"},
            {title:"param",img:"../images/profil.png"}
         ];
       }
    </script>
    <div ng-controller="menuCtrl">
      <div ng-repeat="menu in menus">
        <a href="#"><img src={{menu.img}}></a>
        <h3>{{menu.title}}</h3>
      </div>     
    </div>
 </body>
```

Comment: where is the ng-app? you need to define the angular module in your code... add this var app = angular.module('myApp', []); and then in the html add either in body or better yet add a top div and add ng-app="myApp", you can look at w3school for a short example http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_controllers.asp

Comment: You need to initialize your angular app and declare your controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way of coding is not supported by angular 1.4.7 however it is supported by angular <1.3.0.

I recommend you to follow this style of coding https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController

Answer (score 0):

ngApp: [ng-app description](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp)

```
<body ng-app>
```

Or

```
<html ng-app>
```

Use this directive to auto-bootstrap an AngularJS application. The ngApp directive designates the root element of the application and is typically placed near the root element of the page - e.g. on the  or  tags.

This automatically bootstraps your angular application and then all is good to go. But I like to bootstrap it manually on DOM ready event.

It's upto you. If you are building a sample app and trying to learn then ng-app is fine for you, but in case of large application you should need to make Modules.